# Testcafe doesn't recognize my DOM in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automated-tests, create-react-app, testcafe

I'm new into testcafe, and trying to run a simple test 
on a client which made by `create-react-app`, but for some reason, I can't reach the DOM,
and use the react selectors.

My client:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

function(App){
    return(
        <Button>my button</Button>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is my test:

```
fixture `Record Page`
.page('http://localhost:3000')

test('try', async t=>{
    await t
        .click(ReactSelector('Button')) //from Material UI
        .wait(100000)
})
```

Error:

`the specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.`

which related to the 'Button'

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with `testcafe-react-selectors` module and material UI components. For additional details, see the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors/issues/144) in `testcafe-react-selectors` repository.